# SetInterval withing setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is like:

```
var autoSaveTextInterval = null;
var autosaveText = function () {
    if ($("#textbox").is(':visible') && (filterID != 3 && filterID != 13 && threeTextarea == false)) {
        autoSaveTextInterval = setTimeout(function () {
            if (filterID != 3 && filterID != 13 && threeTextarea == false) {
                document.getElementById('autosave').innerHTML = "Last saved about just now";
            }
            else {
                clearInterval(autoSaveTextInterval);
            }
        }, 20000);
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(autoSaveTextInterval);
    }
}
setInterval(autosaveText, 10000);
```

After 10 sec `autosaveText` function will be called..now what I want to do is if  condition is true of `autoSaveTextInterval` then stop execution for 20 sec after 20 sec execute 10 sec interval function..I have tried above code but not working perfectly as it doesnot clear interval of `autoSaveTextInterval`

Comment: `clearInterval` is a **javascript function** @Kel to clear the `interval` set using `setInterval`

Comment: @Kel Uh, built-in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying the clean up the logic and I end up with the following code.

```
var autosaveText = function () {
    if ($("#textbox").is(':visible') && (filterID != 3 && filterID != 13 && threeTextarea == false)) {
        document.getElementById('autosave').innerHTML = "Last saved about just now";
        setTimeout(autosaveText, 20000);
    } else {
        setTimeout(autosaveText, 10000);
    }
}
setTimeout(autosaveText, 10000);
```

Explanation:

1. Run autosaveText after 10 seconds.
2. In autosaveText, if the condition is true, show text and then schedule the next save after 20 seconds. If it is not, re-check in 10 seconds.

This is cleaner because it does not need any references nor `clearInterval`. But I'm not quite sure if this is what you want. Please comment if your desired logic differs from this implementation, and I will try to update the code.

**UPDATE:** Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3jd1qe1t/

Please note the fiddle is modified for demonstration purposes.

- The timeout is changed to 1 seconds / 2 seconds instead of 10/20 for easier testing.
- The condition is replaced by a checkbox because I don't know about your condition like `filterID`. Checking the checkbox enables auto-saving.
- A message saying `Disabled...` is shown when `autosaveText` is called with auto save disabled.

Comment: Its not working..I understand ur logic but it checks only for once

Comment: How did you know it checks only for once? Did you put `console.log` in autosaveText to track its execution?

Comment: yeah i put `console.log`

Comment: I will try to do a fiddle for that. Wait a moment.

Comment: @debin I added fiddle in the answer.

Comment: yah will try this in my logic :) thnku